# how to solve TypeError: collection.update(...) is not a function in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am getting this error only on update().

```
 collection.update({ Id: parseInt(orderId) }, { $set: { status: updatedStatus } })
(function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
       console.log(err);
 } else {
      console.log(results);
      console.log('updated successfully');
}
```

and my mongoldb version is "mongodb": "^3.0.2".

Comment: What do you've as collection ? usually on a mongoose model(let's say you've defined a mongoose model with model name as person for a collection called person) then you can directly call mongoDB's functions like person.update() & but if you haven't defined a model then you've to do something like this on db connection object :: db.getCollection('person').update()

Comment: var collection = db.get().collection('Order');

Comment: Did you try this :db.getCollection('person').update() ??